# How do I get form submit event listener to work in js?

Tags: javascript

I am replacing some jquery codes with vanilla js, and I am having trouble with the form submit event listener

```
<!-- html -->
<form name="myForm">
   <input type="text" name="name" />
   <button type="button">Click me</button>
</form>
```

```
/* jquery code that works */
$myForm = $("form[name=myForm]")
$("form button").on("click", function(e){
   $myForm.submit()
})

$myForm.on("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log("Submitting form")  
})
```

```
/* vanilla js replacement */
myForm = document.querySelector("form[name=myForm]")
myForm.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function(){
   myForm.submit()
})

myForm.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log("Submitting form")
})
```

In the vanilla js, the form submit event listener does not seem to be triggered when the form is submitted programmatically.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A form's submit event listener won't be triggered when you use the `.submit()` method on the HTMLFormElement:

> The submit event fires when the user clicks a submit button (
> or `<input type="submit">`) or presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> while editing a field (e.g.
> `<input type="text">`) in a form. The event is not sent to the form when
> calling the `form.submit()` method directly.
>
> - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)

You can use the [`.requestSubmit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit) method instead, which does trigger the onsubmit event handler of the form and performs [constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) on the form:

```js
const myForm = document.querySelector("form[name=myForm]")
myForm.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function() {
  myForm.requestSubmit();
})

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log("Submitting form");
})
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <button type="button">Click me</button>
</form>
```

The main downside to this method is that, unlike jQuery's `.submit()` method, `.requestSubmit()` has weaker [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=requestSubmit), now with around 89% of major browsers supporting it.

Comment: Wow, the browser support is really poor!  https://caniuse.com/#search=requestSubmit  That makes it a no go for us

Comment: @user3628119 yes, which is unfortunate :/ You can consider using a [polyfill](https://github.com/javan/form-request-submit-polyfill) for it if browser compatibility is a concern

Comment: Nice, but the event is triggered two times with this code

Comment: @MarcGarcia Make sure you're using a `type="button"` on your submit button: `<button type="button">Click me</button>` (if the issue is with the polyfil I linked from my other comment, then you can then perhaps consider adding an issue to the repo)